# Can one have a condition like this in semidefinite programming?

Tags: optimization

Is it possible to have the following condition in a semidefinite programming as a constraint?

$
         M=
            \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
             a & \sqrt{u} \\
             \sqrt{u} & b \\
                \end{array} } \right]
        \geq 0$

where $\geq 0$ means positive semidefinite.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that *a*, *b*, and *u* are real variables in your semidefinite program, the answer is negative.

The important fact here is that each constraint in a semidefinite program defines a convex set.  Your condition cannot be written as a constraint in a semidefinite program because the set of points (*a*, *b*, *u*) ∈ ℝ<sup>3</sup> that satisfy the condition is not convex.  I suggest that you try to prove that this set is indeed not convex, but here is a proof (put the mouse cursor in the box below to show the proof):

> Proof: (*a*, *b*, *u*) = (1, 1, 1) and (*a*, *b*, *u*) = (3, 3, 9) satisfy the condition, but their midpoint (*a*, *b*, *u*) = (2, 2, 5) does not satisfy the condition.

Comment: However, if there are some constraints over $a$, $b$ and $u$ it can be, right?

Comment: @Alex Grilo: Clearly it all depends on what kind of constraints you are thinking of.  For example, if one of a, b, and u is a constant, then the condition in the question can be easily written as a constraint in a semidefinite program, although this is a silly example.